A solution to "force" sharing of plain text between two parties
I am looking for a cryptography-based solution for a problem that I am working on which is depicted in the below figure at a high-level.

A source $S$ has a sensitive string flag $f$ which they do not want to share with a peer $P$. However, the source $S$ needs to share $f$ with $V$ at a later time. $V$ can communicate with both $P$ (in real-time) and with $S$ (at a later time). Both $P$ and $S$ can co-operate with each other. There is a communication latency of 100ms between all parties.
Is there any way we can guarantee (or at least with high probability and without incurring high communication cost between $S$ and $P$) that $S$ has to share the text flag $f$ with $P$?
A non-solution: HMAC
As the above might be a bit confusing, I want to clarify this problem with a non-solution. I am hoping this will give an idea of what needs to be achieved.
Assume that $V$ gives $P$ a newly generated seed $s$, which they are required to use to generate $\mathsf{HMAC}(f,s)$ as proof that $P$ has seen $f$. The idea for $V$ is that they will later ask $S$ to share the flag $f$ and re-compute $\mathsf{HMAC}(f,s)$ and make sure it matches the old value. However, $P$ can easily subvert this entire process by co-operating with $S$. $P$ can give $s$ to $S$ so that $S$ will generate $\mathsf{HMAC}(f,s)$ themselves and return it to $P$ who will then forward it to $V$. This way, $V$'s plan is compromised at a cost of only 200ms.
But, is there anyway to increase this communication cost? I am hoping that some alternative to HMAC which works at a character-by-character level can help here. But, I am open to any suggestions you might have as I might be completely wrong here.

If V needs to prove knowledge of something and P cannot forge that proof, what does V know/have that P does not - for example, V might know a private key for which S has the corresponding public key...

I don't know how clear my description was - but here are some more details regarding each one's roles.
V: V wants to be assured (as much as possible) that P has seen flag f.
S: S produces flag f and wants to pass the assurance check done by V while as much as possible, avoid sharing flag f with P.
P: P wants to cooperate with S as required and help pass the assurance check from V. So, P will do whatever S wants them to do.
Does this help?


Is there any way we can guarantee (or atleast with high probability and without incurring high communication cost between $S$ and $P$) that $S$ has to share the text flag $f$ with $P$?

The most trivial way I can think of is to require $P$ to send to $S$ the text of $f$ ("a secret string that I don't want to share with $P$").  If $P$ goes and asks $S$ for what the answer should be (as in your HMAC attempt), well, by doing that, $P$ learns $f$, and so the objective has been met.
As far as I can see, that meets all the requirements you asked for - are there any additional requirements that this doesn't meet?
